# How to expose a collection of items from MVC model to a MVC view (*.cshtml) in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a MVC model oject that contains a collection of object. I want to expose the MVC model as user input fields on a MVC view.

Below is MVC model and domain model

```
 public class BookModel
    {
        public BookModel(Book book)
        {
            this.Authors = book.Authors;
        }   

        public List<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    }

    public  class Book
    {
        public List<Author> Authors = new List<Author>();
    }

    public class Author
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Below is the Action method in controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {

            BookModel model = GetBookModel(id);
            return View(model);
        }
```

The problem is that, the generated view (*.cshtml) does NOT have the input fields for the collection authors.

Any idea would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you need a dropdown to select an author or do you need like a checkbox list?

Comment: Can you paste the code for your view? If you are using the scaffolding it might not necessarily generate this code for you...you will have to create it yourself. How exactly do you want it to look? Do you want to show a table, an unordered list, etc?

Comment: Thanks. It is an edit view, thus it can be a table, with one row for one author. Each row has a name label, and name text field for editing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that, the generated view (*.cshtml) does NOT have the
>   input fields for the collection authors.

The ASP.NET MVC new View wizard does its best. From there its up to you.

So inside `Edit.cshtml` you could use editor templates:

```
@model BookModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Text</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Authors)
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
}
```

and then define a editor template for an Author (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Author.cshtml`) which will be rendered automatically for each element of your collection:

```
@model Author
<tr>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Text)</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks. How MVC find the Author.cshtml within EditorTemplates folder? Is there tutorial link for this? Thanks again.

Comment: @Pingpong, it's a convention. It looks at the type (not the name) of the elements in your collection which is `Author`. Then it looks for a view named `Author.cshtml` first inside `~/Views/YourController/EditorTemplates` and if it doesn't find one it looks in `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates`. The same concept exists for display templates as well where you simply replace Editor by Display everywhere. Those two are called templated helpers.

Comment: the name EditorTemplates within the path:~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Author.cshtml, must it named EditorTemplates? Can it be ~/Views/Shared/Author.cshtml? How to name the file within the Shared folder?

Comment: @Pingpong, yes it must be inside EditorTemplates. That's the convention.

Comment: I wonder if you could have a look at this question. Thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843500/how-to-define-asp-net-mvc-view-model-for-parent-child-relationship-and-its-view

Comment: Putting elements that cannot stand on their own outside of the template which they depend on is bad practice.  In this case, having a template which produces table rows in a template that does not define the table.

Comment: @NickLarsen, that's the reason why you could use the `~/Views/SomeSpecificController/EditorTemplates/Author.cshtml` instead of using the Shared folder.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: A razor helper would be better suited in this case.  Templates should be free standing.

Comment: @NickLarsen, I don't agree with you. I will have to write loops in my views. I hate loops :-) Those loops often lead to wrong names of the input fields, wrong ids, etc... I would like to rely on conventions so that the framework works for me and I don't have to write code. So no, I wouldn't use a helper in this case. But of course everyone has his own vision of things, that's why I love ASP.NET MVC, and I appreciate your vision.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Fair enough, we can agree to disagree :)